# Error on migrating angular from 1.2 to 1.4 - Q is undefined

Tags: angularjs

When i updated angularjs from 1.2 to 1.4 exception is thrown in console `TypeError: Q is undefined` .

On Debugging i found that there is some thing in `'ngAnimate'`
when i use this no error is shown

```
var app = angular.module('taskWebApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

when i change and remove 'ngAnimate' then there is no exception

```
var app = angular.module('taskWebApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-loading-bar', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
```

stacktrack

```
Error: Q is undefined
ha@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular-animate.js:2:422
M@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular-animate.js:2:1334
F@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular-animate.js:2:2138
.enter/<@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular-animate.js:2:4198
gf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular.min.js:132:273
gf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular.min.js:134:359
f/q<@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular.min.js:147:128
e@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular.min.js:42:469
If/l.defer/c<@http://localhost:49406/App/frameworks/angular.min.js:45:299
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code.

Comment: Are you using the same version for angular and angular-animate? Are the 2 other modules compatible with angular 1.4? Please use non-minified versions of the libraries. Errors are much easier to identify.

Comment: Thanks @JB that's works. You helped me twice today..